# How to truncate/modify filenames in batches in R?

Tags: r, regex, string, filenames, truncate

I have a long list of CSV files, for examples they look like this:

```
names <- c("CHE1Q_S1001M1_20220615_025815_AM_Original.csv", "CHE2Q_S1002M1_20220615_030435_AM_Original.csv", "CHE6Q_S1053M2_20220615_033828_PM_Original.csv")
```

and I wish to batch shorten them into:
**"CHE1Q_S1001M1.csv", "CHE2Q_S1002M1.csv", "CHE6Q_S1053M2"**

I have tried using the `sub()` function like this:

```
sub('_.*', '', names)
```

but it only returns
"CHE1Q" "CHE2Q" "CHE6Q".

Or:

```
sub('_.*\\_', '', names)
```

gave "CHE1QAverageSpectrum.csv" "CHE2QAverageSpectrum.csv" "CHE6QAverageSpectrum.csv"

I don't know how to make it ignores the first underscore but remove everything from the second underscore.

The best I can get is two steps:

```
names <- sub('_', '', names)
names <- sub('_.*', '', names)
```

and I can get the information but can't get the underscore in the middle: "CHE1QS1001M1" "CHE2QS1002M1" "CHE6QSB053M2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex lookahead to identify strings before the second underscore.

Explanation:

- `^` starts of the string
- `.+?` any number of characters
- `_` followed by a underscore
- `.+?` again any number of characters
- `(?=_)` match one character before `_` (this is your second underscore)
- `(.+?_.+?(?=_))` put everything mentioned above into a capture group (note the bracket `()` surrounding it)
- `.*` match any characters after the capture group till the end of the string
- `\\1.csv` call back the strings in the capture group and add ".csv" after it

```
sub("^(.+?_.+?(?=_)).*", "\\1.csv", names, perl = T)
[1] "CHE1Q_S1001M1.csv" "CHE2Q_S1002M1.csv" "CHE6Q_S1053M2.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you Benson for the detailed explanation! I will look into using regex.